# Use a function in an R package that depends on another, different function

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen

I am trying to use the function `Mclust()` from the `mclust` package in another, different package.

However, it appears that `Mclust()` requires another function, `mclustBIC`, from the `mclust` package in order to work:

```
mod1 = mclust::Mclust(iris[,1:4])
#> Error in mclustBIC(data = structure(c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, : could not find function "mclustBIC"
summary(mod1)
#> Error in summary(mod1): object 'mod1' not found
```

Loading the package first results in this working:

```
library(mclust)
#> Package 'mclust' version 5.3
#> Type 'citation("mclust")' for citing this R package in publications.
mod1 = mclust::Mclust(iris[,1:4])
summary(mod1)
#> ----------------------------------------------------
#> Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
#> ----------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> Mclust VEV (ellipsoidal, equal shape) model with 2 components:
#> 
#>  log.likelihood   n df       BIC       ICL
#>        -215.726 150 26 -561.7285 -561.7289
#> 
#> Clustering table:
#>   1   2 
#>  50 100
```

But it is not clear to me how to do this in a package.

In my package, I tried to add `@importFrom mclust mclustBIC` to the Roxygen documentation, but this did not work.

So, my question: How can I use, or import, this function that seems to be required by the function I am trying to use?

Comment: Import the entire `mclust` package rather than just that one function.

Comment: Thank you! That's in Roxygen, correct - `@import mclust`?

Comment: Yes, you do it in Roxygen and it takes care of the rest.

Comment: this worked, tnx